# Preference deactivating on its own in a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferences

I have a PreferenceActivty in my Android app, which due to compatibility reasons I use via the getPreferenceScreen() method and some Preference objects which I create in code, mostly CheckBoxPreference and SwitchPreference.

Up to the previous version of my app there were 8 preferences in total and everything worked fine, but now I added 2 more preferences and I'm experiencing a REALLY weird issue.

The second preference on the screen is a SwitchPreference. When I open the activity, it is checked. If I scroll down the screen without actually changing anything, suddenly its value is automatically set to OFF. I tried adding an OnChangeListener to the Preference and implementing OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, but the results are the same: once that particular Preference disappears from the screen, it is turned OFF. If it's set to OFF, it keeps its value and the change listener is not called.

Does anyone have any idea as to why could this be happening? I'm completely lost...

Thanks in advance!

---

The code for my preferences is basically this, repeated 5 times for 5 different settings, on the onCreate method:

```
controlWifiPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
controlWifiPreference.setKey(Constants.PREF_1_KEY);
getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(controlWifiPreference);

wifiPreference = new SwitchPreference(this);
wifiPreference.setKey(Constants.PREF_2_KEY);
getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(wifiPreference);
```

Since the preferences are inside a TabActivity, on the onResume method I call setChecked() for every preference to set its value again, though I'm not sure that it's completely neccessary.

And, finally, I have an onSharedPreferenceChanged method that activates/deactivates preferences when others are clicked, because I couldn't get the setDependency method to work. It's something like this (again, repeated five times):

```
if (key.equals(controlWifiPreference.getKey())) {
    wifiPreference.setEnabled(controlWifiPreference.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: Please show us your preferences code. Have you tried cleaning your project in eclipse? Have you tried different android versions? Have you setup some onScroll listener?

Comment: Thanks for the reply afterburner, I have added the code to the original question. 


I tried cleaning the project (like a hundred times :)), and tried Android 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2, with the same results. I haven't tried lower Android versions because I'm using SwitchPreference.

And I've found something more... if I replace the SwitchPreference with a CheckBoxPreference, it doesn't change its value. Could it be a bug with SwitchPreference itself?

Comment: How you implemented preferences inside TabActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was an Android bug in the SwitchPreference class. Someone (who I'm VERY thankful to ;)) reported it to b.android.com and even posted a workaround. It's all here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26194

Answer (score 0):

How you implemented preferences inside TabActivity?I checked your code in my own IDE inside a PreferenceActivity and its working like a charm.If you need to have some pseudo prefences inside your activity, you should not use prefernces and instead, you will need to use normal forms items and save their values to the preferences manually.here is the code i tested and its working ok:

public class PreferencesFromCode extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

```
private SwitchPreference switchPref;
private CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
}

private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy() {
    // Root
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(
            this);

    // Inline preferences
    PreferenceCategory inlinePrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    inlinePrefCat.setTitle(R.string.inline_preferences);
    root.addPreference(inlinePrefCat);

    // Checkbox preference
    checkboxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    checkboxPref.setKey("checkbox_preference");
    checkboxPref.setTitle(R.string.title_checkbox_preference);
    checkboxPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_checkbox_preference);
    inlinePrefCat.addPreference(checkboxPref);

    // Switch preference
    switchPref = new SwitchPreference(this);
    switchPref.setKey("switch_preference");
    switchPref.setTitle(R.string.title_switch_preference);
    switchPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_switch_preference);
    inlinePrefCat.addPreference(switchPref);

    /*
     * The Preferences screenPref serves as a screen break (similar to page
     * break in word processing). Like for other preference types, we assign
     * a key here so that it is able to save and restore its instance state.
     */
    // Screen preference
    PreferenceScreen screenPref = getPreferenceManager()
            .createPreferenceScreen(this);
    screenPref.setKey("screen_preference");
    screenPref.setTitle(R.string.title_screen_preference);
    screenPref.setSummary(R.string.summary_screen_preference);

    return root;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    /*
     * getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
     * .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
     */

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    Log.i("ghjg", "changed key is : " + key);
    if (key.equals(checkboxPref.getKey())) {
        switchPref.setEnabled(checkboxPref.isChecked());
    }
}
}
```

However you may override `onContentChanged()` and see what happens.